# How to filter out one method call from many others with `expect().to receive()` in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have such a code:

```
class ClassB
  def print_letter(arg)
  end
end

class ClassA
  def self.my_method
    ClassB.print_letter("a")
    ClassB.print_letter("b")
  end
end

RSpec.describe ClassA do
  describe "self.my_method" do
    it "prints a" do
      allow(ClassB)
      expect(ClassB).to receive(:print_letter).once.with("a")
      described_class.my_method
    end
  end
end
```

And I'm getting a failure:

> ```
> #<ClassB (class)> received :print_letter with unexpected arguments
>   expected: ("a")
>        got: ("b")
> ```

Can I do anything with that? Is there any way to force the `receive` method to analyze all method calls and pick the one where arguments match, not only the last one? BTW, this behavior seems confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to give one responsability to one method.

In your case I guess you would like to test that your method return "A" and also "B".

I will recommend you to write a method which will return "A" And another one which return "B".

```
def print_a
  ClassB.print_letter("a")
end

def print_b
  ClassB.print_letter("b")
end

def self.my_method
    print_a
    print_b
  end
```

And then just test your methods separatly, for example:

```
it " Print a" do
  expect(print_a).to eq 'a'
end
```

In this way you don't need to test your `self.my_method`, it will Be overkill.

Comment: Overkill or TDD - we could argue. But yeah, this is a solution that works :)